# Is this proof for $\mathbb{E}(XY|X)=X\mathbb{E}(Y|X)$ correct and standard?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

We know that $\mathbb{E}(XY|X)$ is itself a random variable with respect to $x$. So, to prove the given statement in the title, it suffices to treat $\mathbb{E}(XY|X)$ as a function of $x$ and prove that it holds for any $x$. Hence

$$\mathbb{E}(XY|X)(x)=\mathbb{E}(XY|X=x)=\mathbb{E}(xY|X=x)=x\mathbb{E}(Y|X=x)=\left( X\mathbb{E}(Y|X) \right)(x)$$

Since that holds for any $x$, we conclude that $\mathbb{E}(XY|X)=X\mathbb{E}(Y|X)$. Q.E.D.

This fact, together with the law of total expectation, proves that we have

$$\mathbb{E}(XY)=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(XY|X))=\mathbb{E}(X\mathbb{E}(Y|X))$$

Am I correct?

Comment: I am not comfortable with your $\mathbb{E}(XY|X)(x)$ and $\left( X\mathbb{E}(Y|X) \right)(x)$ as I feel it seems to reverse the process.  Instead I see the initial step as having a function $g(x)=\mathbb{E}_Y(XY \mid X=x)$ and then define  $\mathbb{E}_Y(XY \mid X) = g(X)$; here $\mathbb{E}_Y(XY \mid X)$ is a random variable not a function.  Apart from that, this seems fine

Comment: @Henry  Thanks for your comment. I appreciate it. But I don't understand what you mean by 'it seems to reverse the process'. In what sense? And how does introducing $g(x)$ solve this issue? Could you elaborate please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your definition of conditional expectation. A standard definition of conditional expectation is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_random_variable_2)

Now observe that this is equivalently stated as, for any $\Sigma$-measurable function $f$, $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]$ is the only function $g$ of $Y$ that satisfy
$$\mathbb{E}[g(Y) f(Y)]=\mathbb{E}[Xf(Y)]$$

In your case, $\mathbb{E}[Y|X]$ is a function of $X$ and so $X\mathbb{E}[Y|X]$ too. For any $\Sigma$-measurable function $f$, let $f'(x)=xf(x)$, this is $\Sigma$-measurable, so we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X\mathbb{E}[Y|X]f(X)]&=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|X](X f(X))]\nonumber\\
&\stackrel{(\ast)}{=}\mathbb{E}[Y(X f(X))]\\
&=\mathbb{E}[XY f(X)]\nonumber\\
\end{align}

Where $(\ast)$ follows by definition of the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[Y|X]$. This proves that $\mathbb{E}[XY|X]=X\mathbb{E}[Y|X]$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But you're using measure theory and the Radon-Nikodym theorem. I don't want to use those. Avoiding measure theory, do you think my proof is understandable and right?

Comment: @stressedout I don't think I am using the Radon-Nikodym theorem. Simply the definition of the conditional expectation. Regarding your proof, I may be able to confirm if you gave me your definition of conditional expectation.

Comment: Well, I have never had a course in probability theory to know the measure theory approach, so correct if I'm wrong, but I think that the existence/uniqueness of $g$ in your definition uses Radon-Nikodym. I'm using the classical definition: $\mathbb{E}(X|Y)$ is a function of $y$ given by $\mathbb{E}(X|Y)(y)=\mathbb{E}(X|Y=y)$. Then, the later one can be defined using $\mathbb{E}(X|Y=y)=\int_X xf_X(x|Y=y)dx$. Does my question make sense now?

Comment: Yes, and your proof does too.